# Hacking the source code of iOS app

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I have developed an app for iPhone which communicates with a web server though XML based communication model.

In one of my source files, `NetworkLayer`, I created XML objects and send them to the web server. I have also declared all constants used in my app and also URLs (used to access my web server) in `MyApp_Prefix.pch`.

I want to ask if there is any way that some hacker can get access to my source code of generating XML objects or `MyApp_Prefix.pch` file if he has `.app` file of my app? Can anyone please help me in this regard?

Comment: Having access to the URL is easy if a hacker is in your network and using a packet sniffer. Believe me, I have done it at office with Wireshark :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hacker could reverse-engineer your code with some effort by looking at what your code tells the device to do. With some effort and knowledge of assembly and reverse engineering, one can see much of what your code contains. This does however require some serious effort and lots of time, so for most apps, it is unlikely that anyone would attempt to do so.

A much easier way would be to intercept the data on it's way to or from the server, and unless you are obfuscating the data, encrypting it or using SSL, you can't prevent this.

If you are worried about protecting your data, you should try some simple obfuscation. There are many ways to do this, the most popular one being XOR:ing your data with a key both the client and the server knows. Applying the key will flip the bits in your data and quickly and easily turn it into unreadable gibberish. Applying the same key again will flip the same bits again and you have perfectly readable XML.

It should be noted that XOR Encryption is quite possible and relatively easy to crack, especially since the key has to be stored as a part of the application, but it requires lots of time and effort to break through and doesn't qualify as encryption legally (eg. you shouldn't need to go through the whole Encryption Export thing when releasing the app), while still keeping the data gibberish-y enough to throw off most people - which is usually enough, unless your data is really sensitive, eg. if you're transferring payment credentials or similar.

Answer (score 7):

No, he can't get your source code.  But he can look at the HTTP requests and responses to see what XML you have created and what the server has sent back.  Does that matter?

Comment: Either that (using a proxy like Charles) and/or reverse engineer your code using an analyzer tool like IDA. There is no security in obfuscation -> not having the source code does not prevent anything!

Comment: @rob, how can he look at my HTTP requests and responses? I am using HTTPS.

Comment: [How do I sniff / hijack HTTPS / SSH connections](http://monkey.org/~dugsong/dsniff/faq.html#How%20do%20I%20sniff%20/%20hijack%20HTTPS%20/%20SSH%20connections)